# JMETER 5.2.1 : Why parameters tab is disabled in some of the requests and how to handle requsts in this case

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMETER , I am trying to record my web application and correlate JSESSION IDs and other details.

JSESSION ID , i want to capture from previous request and send as parameter in next request.

But in the next request parameters tab is disabled. I see in some posts that body should be empty to have parameters tab. 
In the attached screenshot , if I make body empty , how do I pass the parameters.can anyone please help me . I am not able to proceed further

[image]

Comment: What/How do you want to send the parameters? if it's inside JSON you don't need Parameters tab, if it's query parameters you don't need Parameters tab, explain what/how you want to send parameters

Comment: From the previous response, i created a variable using reg exp extractor - JSESION . 
so now i want to send the value of the variable JSESION  in this request in JSON format( as shown above screenshot) . how do I do that.where should i give this variable JSESION? please help

Comment: Use `${JSESION}`

Comment: I updated body data with below 
{"sessionId":"","ipAddress":"","autoLogin":"N","numberLoginAttempts":0,"cookie":"${JSESSION}"}
Also I tried 
{"sessionId":"","ipAddress":"","autoLogin":"N","numberLoginAttempts":0,"cookie":${JSESSION}}
both are throwing errors.

Comment: Please check if you have removed the text from body tab and there is no white space which is not allowing you to move to parameters tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing a REST API and want to parameterize the contents of your payload you can just inline the relevant [JMeter Function and/or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly into the request body like:

```
{"sessionId":"","ipAddress":"","autoLogin":"N","numberLoginAttempts":0,"cookie":"JSESSIONID=${JSESION}"}
```

If you will still be experiencing problems use [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) in order to check that:

1. Your `JSESION` variable exists
2. It has expected value